# Unable to use environment variables in VS Code launch configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the following in my workspace `settings.json` file:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
    "AUTH_TOKEN": "secret_XXXXXX"
}
```

However, when trying to pass this via a launch command (defined in `launch.json`):

```
    {
        "name": "Example: Query",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/examples/query.py",
        "args": [ "${env:AUTH_TOKEN}" ]
    }
```

The resulting command contains an empty string for the argument:

```
/usr/bin/env /.../.venv/bin/python /.../debugpy/launcher 58644 -- /.../examples/query.py ""
```

However, if I print the variable from within the script, it is set properly.

I believe there is an ordering issue, such that the `launch.json` commands are generated before the terminal environment is set up - resulting in empty vars.  Any ideas how to propagate the env value to the command line?

**Update:** I have also tried using a `.env` file for the variables (rather than `settings.json`), but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try using "env" in launch.json...

```
{
          "name": "Example: Query",
          "type": "python",
          "request": "launch",
          "program": "${workspaceFolder}/examples/query.py",
          "args": ["${AUTH_TOKEN}"], // using var from env on args
          "env": {
                "AUTH_TOKEN": "XXXX",
                "ENV2" : "XXX"
          }
            
}
```

you can use envs from file too

```
{
    // ...
    "args": ["${AUTH_TOKEN}"],
    "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/local.env",
}
```

Comment: Same result...  The env vars are not resolved in the launch config args.

Comment: try both... declare in `"env":{"AUTH_TOKEN":"XX"}"` and using on args `"args":["${AUTH_TOKEN}"]` ( answer has been refreshed  )

Comment: no dice...  launch just escapes the variable reference.  I've already guessed at many of these solutions, just looking for someone who knows of a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .env file, and then put the variable in there, and read it from the environmental variables in the program instead of it being an argument.

Comment: Yes, but that will change the behavior of the program, which is not desired.  I appreciate the pointer, but still hoping there is a way to pass via command line args, which preserves the intent of the script.  Thanks!